# Does alma mater only refer to universities and colleges?

Tags: vocabulary

I was wondering if the term 'alma mater' can be be used to refer to one's place of work, where one has learnt a lot or is it strictly for universities and colleges?

Comment: Please include the research you have done so far, eg looking up the phrase in a dictionary.

Comment: This is easily googled.

Comment: Max, so far I have search for the meaning of alma mater online and tried to find if anyone else has used this term to refer to a field of work e.g. TV and not just to a university or college. This attempt has been unsuccessful.

Comment: Lambie, I have googled but to no avail. Thanks for advice.

Comment: This is not easy to google!  Alma mater referring to schools overwhelms any other use of alma mater.  I did find two entries for alma mater which did not refer to a school.  This is far fewer than I expected to find.

Comment: Technically, in it's common dictionary meaning, [alma mater](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alma%20mater) refers to a school.  However, the term is often used in a figurative sense.

Comment: (And to find the common dictionary meaning I merely needed to Google `define alma mater`.)

Answer (score 4):

If a guy says "TV is my alma mater" he probably means:

> I didn't go to college, but TV taught me what I need to know.

But perhaps he means

> Even though I went to college, I didn't learn anything important there.  Instead I learned it from TV.

So I guess what I am saying is: even if he says "TV is my alma mater" he is still talking about college, in a negative sense.  That is, he is saying "TV was my university."

Comment: What would it mean to "matriculate from TV"?  Get into syndication or a full season on DVD?

Answer (score 1):

It is an expression traditionally closely associated with universities and schools, but it could be potentially used for any place, it is not a brand:

***[Alma Mater](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Alma%20Mater)*** (n.):

> - late 14c., Latin, literally ***"bountiful mother," a title Romans gave to goddesses, especially Ceres and Cybele,*** from alma, fem. of almus "nourishing," from alere "to nourish" (see old) + mater "mother"
> - First used 1710 in sense of "one's university or school" in reference to British universities.

Etymonline

[Alma mater](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alma_mater) "mother"; pl. [rarely used] almae matres)

> - ***is an allegorical Latin phrase for a university or college.*** It is used to refer to a school which an individual has attended.
> - In English, the phrase is variously translated as "nourishing mother", "nursing mother", or "fostering mother", suggesting that a school provides intellectual nourishment to its students.

Wikipedia

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean Josh. However, I meant to ask if you can use 'alma mater' to refer to a person or a field of work which has greatly influenced you and taught you a lot. My partner for example, is a media professional and he wants to refer to TV as his alma mater. Do you think this would sound correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** easy to google!  Alma Mater referring to schools overwhelms other entries.  The answer of Josh 61 gave the translation of alma mater as 
*bountiful mother*.

If you use alma mater to refer to the place or the source of your most profound education, people will understand.

For example, I can imagine a climber saying: "I went to X University, but the mountains were my true alma mater."  A sailor might  say ".....but the sea was my true alma mater."

I did find one example, a quotation from Malcolm X, in
[goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/801-my-alma-mater-was-books-a-good-library-i-could)

> My alma mater was books, a good library.... I could spend the rest of
>   my life reading, just satisfying my curiosity.

There is also a reference to nature as alma mater in an essay [Negotiating Nature/Wilderness: 
Crèvecoeur and American Identity in *Letters From an American Farmer*](http://archive.vcu.edu/english/engweb/crev.htm)  by Ann M. Woodlief.